# deletebutton in child and addbutton in child are not working

Tags: javascript, clone, addeventlistener, clonenode

I have a problem with my code. the add-button in the parent is working, it adds fine. but in the child the add button does not work, same for the delete button. the deletebutton in my browser only work in the parent, and when I click the delete-button it deletes all fields I added before and refresh the site. Although I added the preventDefault. Is that allowed to used preventDefault multiply times in a file?

Here's my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/q3Lz997m/

Code js-file:

```
const clickBtn = document.querySelector('#addingPerson');
const field = document.querySelector('#inputPerson');
let i = 0;

const deleteField = document.querySelector('.deletePerson');

clickBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const cloneField = field.cloneNode(true);
  cloneField.id = i++;
  field.parentNode.appendChild(cloneField);
});

deleteField.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  field.parentNode.removeChild(field);
});
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [cloneMethod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) doesn't clone event listeners:

> Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values,
>   including intrinsic (in–line) listeners. It does not copy event
>   listeners added using addEventListener() or those assigned to element
>   properties.

You can do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/q3Lz997m/2/

```
const clickBtn = document.querySelector('#addingPerson');
const field = document.querySelector('#inputPerson');
let i = 0;

const deleteField = document.querySelector('.deletePerson');

function deleteDiv(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  d = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
}

function cloneDiv(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const cloneField = field.cloneNode(true);
  cloneField.id = i++;
  e = cloneField.querySelector('#addingPerson');
  e.addEventListener('click', cloneDiv);
  e = cloneField.querySelector('.deletePerson');
  e.addEventListener('click', deleteDiv);
  field.parentNode.appendChild(cloneField);  
}

clickBtn.addEventListener('click', cloneDiv);
deleteField.addEventListener('click', deleteDiv);
```

And a little shorter version https://jsfiddle.net/q3Lz997m/3/:

```
function addEventListeners(e) {
  e.querySelector('#addingPerson').addEventListener('click', cloneDiv);
  e.querySelector('.deletePerson').addEventListener('click', deleteDiv);
}

function deleteDiv(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  d = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
}

function cloneDiv(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  p = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  cloneField = p.cloneNode(true); 
  addEventListeners(cloneField);
  p.parentNode.appendChild(cloneField);  
}

addEventListeners(document.querySelector('#inputPerson'));
```

Also, I don't think that you need preventDefault() unless your buttons are inside a form.

Comment: ah ok, but your code is cloning all divs, right? I tried it, and now it clones all divs :/. and can you explain, why u used so much parentnode :D

Comment: It does not clone all divs. Have you tried my jsfiddle example (https://jsfiddle.net/q3Lz997m/3/)? So much parentNode is because e.target is your button and we want to clone it's grand grand grand grand parent (#inputPerson) :) You can use id as a parameter for those functions.

Comment: and the d? where did you get that? because u doesnt declared it :D like the e. I declared/defined it, because my linter was bitching around. and when I declared it like that: https://jsfiddle.net/q3Lz997m/4/. it clones everything. and the buttons are not working correctly

Comment: the fiddle is working, but not for my code^^. i dont know why :/

Comment: So what's the difference between fiddle and your code? Can your share your code/files, or give me the link to your page?

Comment: the problem is the linter http://eslint.org/. I declared it like jsfiddle.net/q3Lz997m/4. Can I share my code privately? via mail or so?